# SQL query to retrive data from database

Tags: php, mysql

I retrieve items from database based on their location id and quantity more than five items but i want for specific location id retrieve items with quantity more than 0 items

This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(warehouses.item_id), SUM(warehouses.qty) AS qty, items.gender_id, items_dept.desc, items_dept.dept_id, items.msrp,items.rtp
FROM `warehouses`
    JOIN `items`
        ON items.item_id = warehouses.item_id
    JOIN `items_dept`
        ON items_dept.dept_id = items.dept_id
WHERE items.gender_id IN (3,5,6)
AND qty > 5
AND warehouses.wrhs_id IN (20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,38,40,44,47,49,55,60,61)
AND items.dept_id = :catId
AND items.rtp BETWEEN :priceX AND :priceY
GROUP BY warehouses.item_id
ORDER BY warehouses.item_id ASC
```

I want for wrhs_id (44) the quantity not more than 5 but more than 0

Comment: SQL code ? SQL schema ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(warehouses.item_id), SUM(warehouses.qty) AS qty, items.gender_id, items_dept.desc, items_dept.dept_id, items.msrp,items.rtp
FROM `warehouses`
    JOIN `items`
        ON items.item_id = warehouses.item_id
    JOIN `items_dept`
        ON items_dept.dept_id = items.dept_id
WHERE items.gender_id IN (3,5,6)
AND ((
        qty > 5
        AND
        warehouses.wrhs_id IN (20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,38,40,47,49,55,60,61)
    )
    OR (
        qty > 0
        AND
        warehouses.wrhs_id = 44
    )
)
AND items.dept_id = :catId
AND items.rtp BETWEEN :priceX AND :priceY
GROUP BY warehouses.item_id
ORDER BY warehouses.item_id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you can use LIMIT param to specify limit of returned items, but if you retrieve 0 items you made a mistake or there are no data on database

Comment: no i want in query to retrieve items in wrhs_ids (1,2,3,4) and their quantity must be more than five items and retrieve items in wrhs_id(5) and his quantity must be more than 0 items

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(warehouses.item_id), SUM(warehouses.qty) AS qty, items.gender_id, items_dept.desc,items_dept.dept_id,items.msrp,items.rtp
            FROM `warehouses`
            JOIN `items`      ON items.item_id      = warehouses.item_id
            JOIN `items_dept` ON items_dept.dept_id = items.dept_id
            WHERE items.gender_id IN (3,5,6)
            AND qty > 0
            AND warehouses.wrhs_id = 44
            AND items.dept_id = :catId
            AND items.rtp BETWEEN :priceX AND :priceY
            GROUP BY warehouses.item_id
            ORDER BY warehouses.item_id ASC
```